# What is happening when I use parenthesis in this function call to make it behave differently?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise

I wish to wait on the array of promise objects from a series of calls.
But when I use the following call nothing happens:

```
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(processFinalTable());
```

Execution of the code following works as expected:

```
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(processFinalTable);
```

What is going on here at an execution level?

Here is a link to a working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jyza3050/5/)

Comment: Do you ask what's the difference between a function and its execution ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you missed but maybe you'll be interested by  [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Comment: I am missing a compiler that warns me when I do something stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, you are invoking the function processFinalTable, and passing its result to done().

In the second one, you are passing the function itself, which is what done() needs to execute properly.

Comment: Oh my. That means you can return a function from a function call, which implies someone will try and do that and expect others to understand it. Thanks

Comment: Yes. It allows you to do very powerful things, but also very confusing things. Functions are first-class objects in JS.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one,  processFinalTable function executes and done method takes its return value which will try to execute this return value when the process done.

In the second one, done method takes function itself so that it can use it when processes done.

Comment: What on earth have you done

Comment: omg, we answered at the same time. aahahahahah